# Content for doesn't work in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

On one of application's page there is:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<%= tag :meta, property: "fb:app_id", content: ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>
<% content_for :title, @check.title %>
<% end %>
```

And it worked in development, while I was running server at my localhost.

After that I deployed application on heroku. And that simply doesn't work.

What means doesn't work. I load page in development at localhost:

```
<title>Tenta</title>
<meta content="*****************" property="fb:app_id">
```

When I load this page deployed at heroku host, these tags are simply absent.

Why?

Also, If you don't know this particular issue solution, I would appreciate if you adivce me, how can I look what is going on - `heroku logs`  and watching last 150 logs in inconvinient windows console doesn't give me a lot of helpful information.

Comment: Can you go into detail on "simply doesn't work"? Does it not load? And to get a shorter list of logs, try shortening the number of logs you're viewing (or change format): `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits`

Comment: Whats your application.html.erb look like?

Comment: How are you setting `ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]` on Heroku?

Comment: Like muttonlamb said, try setting your FACEBOOK_APP_ID on your production environment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars